# Disable CE windows animation, programmatically?

Tags: c#, embedded, windows-ce, pocketpc

Here is how to do it with a registry key.

```
*  Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\GWE
* Create a DWORD named Animate if it does not already exist
* Edit the DWORD value named Animate
* 0 - Disables Window Animation
  1 - Enables Window Animation
```

However, it needs restart of the device. I would like to know if there is anyway to disable it instantly, programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940383.aspx). There is no animation setting, but maybe if you notify GWES of a different change it will also update the animation state.