# How prevent the form hide after the dialog close (C# Windows Mobile)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm doing a mobile application, all is almost as `WindowsForms` but when I close a `MessageBox` that provoque the multiple dialogs close with `DialogResult` in `DialogResult.OK` I find a problem, the main form it hides.

The structure is as follows:

[image]

program.cs

```
Application.Run(new From1());
```

Form1

```cs
Dialog1 frmDialog1 = new Dialog1());
frmDialog1.ShowDialog(this);
```

Dialog1(Windows Parent)

```cs
Dialog2 frmDialog2 = new Dialog2());
frmDialog2.ShowDialog(this);

if(frmDialog2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
 this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
 this.Close();
}
```

Dialog2(Windows Parent)

```cs
Dialog3 frmDialog3 = new Dialog3());
frmDialog3.ShowDialog(this);

if(frmDialog3.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
 this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
 this.ParentForm.Hide();
 this.Close();
}
```

Dialog3(Windows Parent)

```cs
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Save?", 
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Question, 
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
  this.ParentForm.Hide();
  this.Close();
}
```

**Note: I'm using [DllImport("coredll.dll")] to show full screen

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[Flags()]
public enum FullScreenFlags : int
{
    SwHide = 0,
    ShowTaskbar = 0x1,
    HideTaskbar = 0x2,
    ShowSipButton = 0x4,
    HideSipButton = 0x8,
    SwRestore = 9,
    ShowStartIcon = 0x10,
    HideStartIcon = 0x20

}
static class FullScreen
{

    #region Win32 API Calls

    /// <summary>
    /// The GetCapture function retrieves a handle to the window 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetCapture();

    /// <summary>
    /// The SetCapture function sets the mouse capture to
    /// the specified window belonging to the current thread
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetCapture(IntPtr hWnd);

    /// <summary>
    /// This function can be used to take over certain areas of the screen
    ///  It is used to modify the taskbar, Input Panel button,
    /// or Start menu icon.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("aygshell.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SHFullScreen(IntPtr hwnd, int state);

   /// <summary>
    /// The function retrieves the handle to the top-level 
    /// window whose class name and window name match 
    /// the specified strings. This function does not search child windows.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="lpClass"></param>
   /// <param name="lpWindow"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowW(string lpClass, string
    lpWindow);

    /// <summary>
    /// changes the position and dimensions of the specified window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <param name="w"></param>
    /// <param name="l"></param>
    /// <param name="repaint"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int
    w, int l, int repaint);
    #endregion

    #region General Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// obtain the window handle of a .Net window or control
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="c"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IntPtr GetHWnd(Control c)
    {
        IntPtr hOldWnd = GetCapture();
        c.Capture = true;
        IntPtr hWnd = GetCapture();
        c.Capture = false;
        SetCapture(hOldWnd);
        return hWnd;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set Full Screen Mode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form"></param>
    public static void StartFullScreen(Form form)
    {
        //if not Pocket Pc platform
        if (!Platform.PlatformDetection.IsPocketPC()) 
        {
            //Set Full Screen For Windows CE Device

            //Normalize windows state
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

            IntPtr iptr = form.Handle;
            SHFullScreen(iptr, (int)FullScreenFlags.HideStartIcon);

            //detect taskbar height
            int taskbarHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

            // move the viewing window north taskbar height to get rid of the command 
            //bar 
            MoveWindow(iptr, 0, -taskbarHeight, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height + taskbarHeight, 1);


            // move the task bar south taskbar height so that its not visible anylonger 
            IntPtr iptrTB = FindWindowW("HHTaskBar", null);
            MoveWindow(iptrTB, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, taskbarHeight, 1);
        }
        else //pocket pc platform
        {
            //Set Full Screen For Pocket Pc Device
            form.Menu = null;
            form.ControlBox = false;
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            form.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop Full Screen Mode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form"></param>
    public static void StopFullScreen(Form form)
    {
        //if windows ce return window and taskbar to his original place
        if (!Platform.PlatformDetection.IsPocketPC())
        {
            IntPtr iptr = form.Handle;

            SHFullScreen(iptr, (int)FullScreenFlags.ShowStartIcon);

            //detect taskbar height
            int taskbarHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

            MoveWindow(iptr, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - taskbarHeight, 1);

            IntPtr iptrTB = FindWindowW("HHTaskBar", null);
            MoveWindow(iptrTB, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - taskbarHeight, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, taskbarHeight, 1);

        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Other comment:

I´m calling `this.ParentFormHide();` because I desire that the parent it is hide before then close it. This for prevent then it show wrong, as like the follows:

[image: This is shown when is closing multiple dialogs in cascade]

This is shown when is closing multiple dialogs in cascade

If you know a way to prevent this animation on closing multiple dialogs, please share to me. At present to prevent this, I'm hiding the previous dialog before to close it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it your desire that closing Dialog3 should cascade back and also close Dialog2 and Dailog1?

Comment: Setting the `DialogResult` already closes the current dialog, in the past I've had issues when calling `Close()` afterwards. And why are you calling `this.ParentForm.Hide();`?

Comment: @tcarvin, Yes is it, I desire that closing Dialogs should cascade back.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis First, thanks for answer; Sencond, I'm going to leave to call "Close()". And answering your question, I´m calling "this.ParentFormHide();" because i desire that the parent it is hide before then close it. This for prevent then it show wrong, as like the follows:

Comment: I put in the publication the image with the animation that a want to prevent

Comment: You can disable the animation via a registry setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268631/disable-ce-windows-animation-programatically - but this is of course system-wide.

Comment: Now working correctly, Thanks